# Parsing folder for pairs with bash or AppleScript

Tags: terminal, finder, applescript, bash

I edit RAW photos in Photoshop using Adobe Camera Raw. The way the edits work is any time I work on a picture, Photoshop creates a text file with the same name as the picture to which the edits were made. However, sometimes when I delete an image, or use it in a Photomerge, the XML file stays behind. Thus I now have  a folder with ~1100 RAW images (.NEF), ~1300 text files (.xmp) and a few photoshop files (.psd, .psb).

I would like to parse this folder, using either AppleScript or a bash command, and either mark or delete the .xmp files that do not have a companion RAW file. Logically, the code would be: for every .xmp file, check for a .NEF file with same name. If .NEF does not exist, delete or mark the .xmp file. If .NEF does exist, do nothing.

I am not familiar with AppleScript, and although I am familiar with ffmpeg, diskutil, and basic cd/ls and rsync commands in terminal, I have never attempted something like this and do not know where to start.

So, I was hoping someone on here could:

1. Help decide whether bash or AppleScript is more appropriate here AND
2. Help me write the sequence OR point me to some good resources where I could learn enough (either bash or AppleScript) to write the sequence myself.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57253/discussion-on-question-by-noahl-parsing-folder-for-pairs-with-bash-or-applescrip).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Terminal, change directory, e.g. `cd /path/to/files`, to the location of the target files and then use the following command to delete any `.xmp` file that doesn't have a corresponding `.NEF` file:

```
for f in *.xmp; do [[ ! -f ${f%.*}.NEF ]] && rm "$f"; done
```

Comment: This works perfectly! That's so much easier than I thought it would be!

Comment: Wouldn't `"${f%.*}.xmp"` be the same a `"$f"`?

Comment: @fd0, In this case, yes it's the same and of course works either way. I posted this before having had coffee and was being lazy by copying and pasting changing `${f%.*}.NEF` to `"${f%.*}.xmp"`. I've shortened it now.

Comment: @user3439894 Extra points for a good use of lazy execution.